# jquery mousedown + mouseenter not working

Tags: jquery, mouseevent

I'm trying to use mousedown and mouseenter/mouseleave simultaneously but it's not working. But it's working perfectly well without the mousedown. My intent here is to make the element selectable (the way jQuery UI works).

```
$(document).on("mousedown", function (evt) {
    // draw my selection range ...

    $(".selectable").on("mouseenter", function (evt) {
        evt.stopPropagation();
        // I do my stuff
    });

    $(".selectable").on("mouseleave", function (evt) {
        evt.stopPropagation();
        // I do my stuff
    });
});
```

Using this onmouseleave is triggered right after I enter the element when mousedown.

Comment: what is reason of not using `.hover`

Comment: @dianuj, same result. And as I understood `.hover` is just a shorthand for `.mouseenter`r and `mouseleave` events.